# Redirect all http/www into https://www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What this does is:

- With `http://example.com` it redirects to `https://www.example.com` (this is correct)
- With `https://example.com` it redirects to `https://www.example.com` (this is correct)
- But with `http://www.example.com` it doesn't redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

Please take note that It needs to be not more than 1 chain. It should redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid hardcoding your host name and do both conditions in a single redirect rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just fixed it.

this is the updated code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I can guarantee that this will all do 301 redirect without more than **1 chain**.
I hope this helps some developers out there!.